# Issue accessing a WebResource.axd files content within code

Tags: c#, asp.net, identifier, webresource.axd, encryption

Im trying to combine all css files into one css file.

The trouble is getting the WebResource.axd files included. I know I can do an http request to grab it but I also know i should be able to fetch it within the AssemblyResourceLoader.

The url format is WebResource.axd?d=*encrypted identifier*&t=*time stamp value*

The problem im facing is getting the encrypted identifier decrypted so that i can retrieve the css.

Any help on getting the decrypted identifier or an alternative method of getting the content of a webresource for a page.

Thanks

Update:
Code I found to decrypt id. Next issue to figure out is accessing the content within a resource. Here is the decrypt code

```
public string DecryptWebResourceIdentifier(string urlEncodedData)
{

    byte[] encryptedData = HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenDecode(urlEncodedData);
    string decrypted="";
    Type machineKeySection = typeof(MachineKeySection);
    Type[] paramTypes = new Type[] { typeof(bool), typeof(byte[]), typeof(byte[]), typeof(int), typeof(int) };
    MethodInfo encryptOrDecryptData = machineKeySection.GetMethod("EncryptOrDecryptData", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, paramTypes, null);
    try
    {
        byte[] decryptedData = (byte[])encryptOrDecryptData.Invoke(null, new object[] { false, encryptedData, null, 0, encryptedData.Length });
        decrypted = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedData);
    }
    catch
    {
    }
    return decrypted;
}
```

Comment: I figured out how to decode the encrypted identifier, now im just trying to figure out how to pull out the resource text with the id.

Answer (score 2):

I'll need to suggest you that this could be a bad approach. Dinamically combining CSS can waste resources and application may not perform as you expect so far.

Recommended approach is combining CSS, compressing JavaScript or any client-side optimization in build-time. That's managing MSBuild to do a task that must combine/compress CSS whenever you compile your ASP.NET application.

You can use Yahoo UI library. It has a port for .NET:

- http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/

And, finally, you can implement a very simple MSBuild task like this:

```
<CombineCSS Files="@(CSSFiles)"  />
```

So it'll execute a code that reads text of given file paths (CSSFiles) and appends them to a memory stream, then you can take this stream, convert it to string and compress with YUI.

This task may be added to csproject MSBuild markup source code as a child node of post-build event.

You'll get a file like "Style.css" that may contain ALL CSS code from ALL files and with a good compression!!

Comment: My plan was to combine all the css files then cache the file css file. I have many pages with extra style sheets that cannot be added to some pages. so i wanted to dynamically create compress then cache on the first page load.

Comment: well, you can combine some CSS files, instead of all ones. For example, you can have "AdminArea.min.css", or "HomePage.min.css" and so on, but these are a combination of N files.

Answer (score 1):

what about ClientScriptManager.GetWebResourceUrl

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.getwebresourceurl.aspx

Comment: Thats what Im trying to do, but I dont know the resource name. From reading I am perdy sure that the name is in the encrypted identifier, but i cant figure out how to decrypt it.

Comment: do you have it registered in assembly like [assembly: WebResource("abc.js", "application/x-javascript")] then the name is abc.js

Comment: The resources are being added through 3rd part controls so it would not be easy to find the names without looking at their decompiled code.

Comment: well then I don't know other way how to do it

Answer (score 1):

Using your **DecryptWebResourceIdentifier** method, try this code snippet:

```
string decryptedWebResourceIdentifier = DecryptWebResourceIdentifier(encryptedWebResourceIdentifier);
string assemblyName = null;
string resourceName = decryptedWebResourceIdentifier.Split("|")[1];
string resourceContent;

//Switch between assembly complete name and partial name
if (decryptedWebResourceIdentifier.Split("|")[0].Contains(",")) {
  assemblyName = string.Format("{0}, Version={1}, Culture={2}, PublicKeyToken={3}",   decryptedWebResourceIdentifier.Substring(1).Split("|")[0].Split(",")).Replace("Culture=,", "Culture=neutral,");
} else {
  assemblyName = decryptedWebResourceIdentifier.Split("|")[0].Substring(1);
}

//Gets resource assembly
Assembly resourceAssembly;

//If a assembly partial name is defined, get it's assembly reference or else, get current assembly
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(assemblyName)) {
  resourceAssembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyName);
} else {
  resourceAssembly = this.GetType().Assembly;
}

//Get resource stream and his content
resourceContent = new StreamReader(resourceAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName)).ReadToEnd();
```